# How to get number of facebook members of a group in javascript

Tags: javascript, facebook, facebook-graph-api

I try to use the SDK for javascript on my website. I tried to get the number of members of a facebook group on my page. I found this in the documentation:

```
FB.api(
"/{group-id}/members",
function (response) {
  if (response && !response.error) {
    /* handle the result */
  }
}
```

);

But I really don't know how I have to go further.

I tried this:
In the begin I make the api-call (with the appid I created). Than I tried this code:

```
    FB.api(
    "/{1594137150858447}/members",
    function (response) {
      if (response && !response.error) {
        alert('test')      
       }
    }
);
```

With the numbers equals to a facebook-group. But it doesn't do anything.

Comment: `{}` is not meant to wrap the literal values ... it is intended to be used as `insert value here`

Comment: Ok I changed it, but it doesn't work anyway

Comment: check response in browser dev tools

Comment: I see an error: SCRIPT5022: Error: init not called with valid version 
sdk.js. I use version    : 'v2.3'. Is that not write?

Comment: no idea...read the manual

Answer (score 0):

You need to authorize with the `user_groups` permissions, of course. That being said, the API call would be `/1594137150858447/members` but there is no way to get the number of members with just one API call. You will have to implement [paging](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/graph-api/using-graph-api/v2.3#paging) to go through all group members, because you only get 25 in the result. You can try setting a higher limit, but there is a maximum for that: `/1594137150858447/members?limit=100`

Keep in mind that each "page" counts as separate API call, so be careful with API limits. You may hit it if there are many members.

Edit: The init error (from your comments) means that you did not [initialize the JS SDK](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/javascript/quickstart/v2.3).

Comment: I initialize it, I put the code mentioned in the documentation with my appID. I tried to copy paste the code for a simple like button and that works. So I think I initialized it well ?